# Why must a table with a nonclustered columnstore index be read only?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, columnstore

I was reading [this MSDN article].(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx)

One of the key differences between a clustered and non-clustered index is that a clustered index is updateable.  Fine - but what property of a non clustered index leads it (and the table) to be read only?  Why can a change to the table not be reflected in the index?

Comment: No technical reason. Just not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012 introduced non-clustered columnstore indexes, and the update was not implemented. In SQL Server 2014 columnstore indexes are far more advanced, e.g. we can have clustered columnstore index, which totally replaces row storage with column store, and the indexes in 2014 are already updateable.